# create views with different tables

Tags: mysql, view

```
create view xyz_view as
select 
    t1.sam_time, 
    t2.hos_id,
    (select t1.STAT_VALUE from table_1 t1 where t1.ID = 6 ) as col_1,
    (select t1.STAT_VALUE from table_1 t1 where t1.ID = 24 ) as col_2,
    (select t1.STAT_VALUE from table_1 t1 where t1.ID = 125 ) as col_3,
    (select t1.STAT_VALUE from table_1 t1 where t1.ID = 143 ) as col_4
from
    table_1 t1, table_2 t2
where 
    t1.entity = t2.hos_id;
```

Here i am getting error as:
**subquery returns multiple rows mysql**

when i put limit 1, it returns on one value through out the table. but i want all the rows
is there any other option to get all those data.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't believe you.  If your subqueries return multiple rows, you would end up with a big cartesian product for the view.  Can you edit your question and provide sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the values in a *list* on each row.  Perhaps this is what you want:

```
select 
    t1.sam_time, 
    t2.hos_id,
    (select group_concat(t1.STAT_VALUE) from table_1 t1 where t1.ID = 6 ) as col_1,
    (select group_concat(t1.STAT_VALUE) from table_1 t1 where t1.ID = 24 ) as col_2,
    (select group_concat(t1.STAT_VALUE) from table_1 t1 where t1.ID = 125 ) as col_3,
    (select group_concat(t1.STAT_VALUE) from table_1 t1 where t1.ID = 143 ) as col_4
from table_1 t1 join
     table_2 t2
     on t1.entity = t2.hos_id;
```

You should also learn to use proper `join` syntax, which uses the `join` keyword and the `on` keyword for the conditions between tables.